# Is there truly no semantic notion that underlies the prefix 'for-'?

Tags: etymology

McWhorter, J. [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter). [*What Language Is* (2011)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159240720X), [pp. 87-88](https://books.google.com/books?id=xFQbHnvLonkC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%22there%E2%80%99s+no+use+even+trying+to+get+a+sense+of+a+single+meaning%22&source=bl&ots=o62LvmVhmB&sig=CQRQ042uum0E80-5kFWsXXF8ogg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEpuX_6bvcAhVM04MKHTfnDT4Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> [image]

Both McWhorter overhead and [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/for-) avouch no single semantic notion that can underlie all of *for-*'s meanings. But I'm not convinced that they looked hard enough? If a single semantic notion can underlie a conjunction as polyfunctional as ["as"](https://www.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/83435p/cmv_no_semantic_notion_explains_and_underlies_the/dvf4zzd/), then can't there be one for *for-*?

Comment: The wiktionary page for the prefix *[for-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for-#English) provides three semantic uses: `Meaning "far", "away"; "from", "out" e.g. forbid, forget, forsay; forbear, fordeem.` |||| `Meaning "completely", "to the fullest extent" e.g. forbreak; superseded by combinations with "up" in senses where no upward movement is involved, e.g. forgive = give up (one's offenses), forgather = "gather up", forbeat = "beat up", etc.` |||| `Very; excessively.
forolded (“very old”)
fornigh (“very near”)`

Comment: @ukemi Doesn't your comment support McWhorter's argument though? What semantic notion would underlie those three meanings?

Comment: I gotta say, Area 51, the more McWhorter you post, the more I dislike him. Yes, he's a populariser, but he's being unnecessarily glib at it.

Comment: There is a problem with your question other than the kind of problem that gets anti-Etymologists to downvote it: it's impossible to prove a negative. "I'm not convinced that they looked hard enough?" In fact, that's exactly what The American Heritage Dictionary tried to do. I'd argue it's pointless to posit a single meaning here. I'd also argue that McWhorter's _for-_ = "oink" is ornery: the "far" meaning is opaque synchronically, but the "completely" meaning is not (and was productive much more recently).

Comment: Why should there only be one meaning? Polysemy and homonyms are extremely common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thanks to @ukemi for pointing out https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for-#English

There is metaphor and hyperbole at work here diachronically, and I'd argue we can't meaningfully posit a single unifying synchronic meaning. Moreover, the three meanings listed in Wiktionary are not synchronically productive; even less motivation to seek a single unifying synchronic meaning now.

> From Middle English *for-, vor-*, from Old English *for-, fer-, fær-, fyr-* (“far, away, completely”, prefix), from the merger of Proto-Germanic **fra-* ("away, away from"; see fro, from) and Proto-Germanic **fur-, *far-* (“through, completely, fully”)
>
> 1. (no longer productive) Meaning "far", "away"; "from", "out" e.g. *forbid, forget, forsay; forbear, fordeem*.
> 2. (no longer productive) Meaning "completely", "to the fullest extent" e.g. forbreak; superseded by combinations with "up" in senses where no upward movement is involved, e.g. forgive = give up (one's offenses), forgather = "gather up", forbeat = "beat up", etc.
> 3. (dialectal) Very; excessively. forolded (“very old”), fornigh (“very near”)

The first two meanings, "far" and "completely", are not even etymologically identified, but a merger of distinct but similar looking words.

There is a metaphor that can be invoked to explain "far" > "completely"; in fact, Latin *per-* has both meanings, and I'm not seeing a claim that they are etymologically distinct. (For all I know, **fra-*  and **fur-, *far-* are also cognate). That metaphor is COMPLETION IS A JOURNEY (which is yet another variant of the localist standby, TIME IS SPACE). The further you have gone on a journey, the closer to complete your journey is. A Modern English counterpart to that metaphor is *all the way*: literally it refers to a completed journey, metaphorically it refers to any completed task (*I read the book all the way through*.)

But it's a metaphor that's added to the meaning of "far": farness has the primary meaning of a long distance, and the notion of a journey being complete is external to it (unlike *all the way*, which indicates completeness both literally and figuratively). For that reason, you could not argue a synchronic meaning in common to *for-* = "far" and *for-* = "complete" at any stage.

The "very" meaning relates to "completely" as hyperbole, comparable to the modern meaning of *literally*. "I am *fornigh* = completely near" is literally impossible, and a hyperbole for "I am very near", just as "I am literally right there" when you're not there yet. Again, a hyperbolic use of a term cannot be conflated in truth-conditional semantics with the literal sense of the term.